# redirect search results to different page

Tags: search, search-results, xslt

I have one list and search custom search scope is defined for that list. so that it will search only in that list. so the search results will be nothing but the list items! Now My requirement is, after getting search results on results page, when user will click on any search result, instead of opening that list item (form), I want to open other .aspx page where I will be showing data of that list item in html.
In other words instead of opening list item directly I want to show that data on other .aspx page with some good fashion.

so for this is there any xslt modifications needed.? can someone please assist?
what I guess is, I will need to change some xslt and pass that list items(results) ID  to other page..!??
New to xslt.! Can someone please help?

Comment: What version / SKU of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Sharepoiont 2010...

Comment: any one ha any idea..!!???

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on XSLT out there.  You can do just about anything with the XSLT template.  This being such a specific page source and target I would probably just drop JavaScript on the page and dynamically modify the target URL's to point to your destination.